# How the assert statement stops the program?

Tags: java

I don't get how the assert statement stops the program? Is it throws an exception or something else? If it throws an exception can I catch this exception doing something like:

```
try {  
    assert result != null;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //some code
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to stop an assert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't get how the assert statement stops the program?

The code

```
assert test;
```

is much the same as

```
if (!$disabledAssertions && test) throw new AssertionError();
```

Any exception or error can be caught, but that doesn't make it a good idea.

An Error is not an Exception so `catch(Exception)` will not catch it.

Comment: Then why people use assert statement instead of "...throw new AssertionError();". Some people says you can disable them but they are using seperate test classes and why they want to disable them?

Comment: @PeterLawrey So how can I set `disabledAssertions = true`?

Comment: @MaximShoustin Assertions are disabled by default, You can enable them with `-ea` or specific ones http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html

Comment: @hellzone a) assert is shorter, less typing b) for code in production, they are turned off by default.  This is a reason you might not use `aasert` i.e. you always want the check to be performed, but a different Exception is likely to be best.

Comment: @hellzone asserts are used to check expectations (e.g. you writing some method and assuming that input string isn't empty, some current field isn't null and so on, otherwise function would not work properly), normally they are disabled in *production* environment so the do not **affect performance**, but can be enabled in *development* environment if you suspect that something in your program gone wild. So you **very unlikely** would want to catch assertions -- their main goal is to scream loudly when something going wrong instead of silently swallowing [logical] errors.

Answer (score 2):

It throws [`AssertionError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html). The details are spelled out in [JLS §14.10 The assert Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10).

Note that assertions can be disabled, in which case `assert` is a no-op.